# Is there a way to enhance antialiasing level in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, antialiasing

I place some images into VSE strips, animate it with resizing and rotating curves. When I render my VSE scene into series of png files I see some ugly pixelated bounds of my images. Well. yeah it's not the ugliest pixelated bounds I've ever seen to be honest but I wish I could have better antialiasing support in VSE if this possible.

I've noticed about some trick with upscaling the scene to higher resolution and then downscale it back with some good filter but I think it's not the best solution specially for images like screenshots, etc that should be very sharp.

Is there a chance to have any control over this issue?